# Rails basics - counting most used values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A widget has_one type, and type has_many widgets.  I'd like to count which types are the most commonly assigned to my widgets (top 3 used).

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

The way I have the database structured is the widgets table has a type_id, which is assigned by a select when creating the widget.

I imagined that this would be a method I'd define in the model of my widget.rb, since I'd need to collect all my widgets before counting up the types and giving them a "score" if you will.

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to figure out which of the types are most used - my goal is to return them from the method in the model, which is created as an array and assigned to a variable in the controller.

The view them pulls the top three by simply calling first three values of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your widgets should [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) type, as the widget table would be the one holding the type_id. Next, I suggest using the Rails [counter_cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) (scroll down to the options).

First you would run a migration like:

```
class AddTypesWidgetsCount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :types do |t|
      t.integer :widgets_count
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :types do |t|
      t.remove :widgets_count
    end
  end
end
```

Then add the `:counter_cache => true` attribute to your belongs_to method.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, :counter_cache => true
end
```

After that you can create a scope that sorts types by `widgets_count`. Your type model could look something like:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
  named_scope :top_three, :order => 'widgets_count DESC', :limit => 3
end
```

Then you can call `Type.top_three` to get the top three types by widget count. Or, without the named scope, you can call something like `Type.find(:order => 'widgets_count DESC', :limit => 3)`, but the named scope will allow chaining.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  I have to remember the difference with :has_one and :belongs_to in relation to having that _id field.

I didn't know about the counter cache! From your description, it looks like it'll do the trick.  Thanks for the tip and I'll get to work. :)

Comment: Update: wow, works like a charm and so easy!  I love that I can implement this in many places for my users.  Thanks again, Benjamin.  I hope you have a great remainder of the weekend.